# DBI::OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, dbi

On rails console when I tried to connect to postgres database which on machine having ip address suppose xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

Gem installed

```
gem 'dbi'  
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
gem 'dbd-pg'
```

I also granted all permission to 'postgres' user and restarted postgres server on this xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx machine

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test TO postgres WITH GRANT OPTION
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

I am getting following error.

> 1.9.3p448 :001 > dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Pg:test:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "postgres", "")
>
> DBI::OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>     Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting   TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

```
from /home/ashwini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/dbd-pg-0.3.9/lib/dbd/pg/database.rb:82:in `rescue in initialize'
from /home/ashwini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/dbd-pg-0.3.9/lib/dbd/pg/database.rb:41:in `initialize'
from /home/ashwini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/dbd-pg-0.3.9/lib/dbd/Pg.rb:157:in `new'
from /home/ashwini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/dbd-pg-0.3.9/lib/dbd/Pg.rb:157:in `connect'
from /home/ashwini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/driver.rb:33:in `connect'
from /home/ashwini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:148:in `connect'
from (irb):1
from /home/ashwini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /home/ashwini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/ashwini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please tell me where am going wrong.

Thank you...

Comment: Well, did you check what the error message advised? In particular the `on port 5432` part? (By the way, 8.3 is obsolete. You need to plan an upgrade.)

Comment: No my postgres is updated..sry forgot to remove old version from command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect with `psql` and run:

```
SHOW port;
```

Betcha the port given isn't `5432`. You're probably also on a mac; it's common for mac users to have some binaries linked to the `libpq` supplied by the operating system (an old PostgreSQL) and some to the `libpq` of a PostgreSQL they installed themselves. These can have different default socket directories and different TCP port defaults.

You should also:

```
SHOW listen_addresses ;
```

and make sure it is `*`. If it instead says `localhost` then your PostgreSQL isn't listening on external IPs, only the local loopback. In that case, you should change that in the config file. See the introductory PostgreSQL documentation.

If you've confirmed that PostgreSQL is listening on the IP and port of interest, you should make sure you don't have a firewall blocking connections from outside machines. That would usually result in a timeout, not a connection refused error, though.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Ashwini OK. Any chance you have more than one PostgreSQL installed? What port is the PostgreSQL you want to connect to running on? Is it listening on the destination IP address? Run `SHOW listen_addresses ;`

Comment: Actually Postgres is installed on another Ubuntu 12.04 machine (I am also using Ubuntu 12.04 ) and I am trying to connect to that database. I have not specified any port number.It may be default port used by postgres

Comment: @Ashwini So... maybe you should check that's the port that the server is running on, like the error message says?

Comment: ok I have run the command port -> 5432 and listen_addresses ->  localhost

Comment: @Ashwini Well, there you go then. It isn't listening on all network interfaces.

Comment: Thank you :) ya it works, but if I put `listen_addresses = '*'` is there any side effects of this?

Comment: @Ashwini Yes, per the documentation on `listen_addresses`. Setting it to `*` makes it listen on *all* interfaces, not just loopback.